# Wait for java script confirm message response from server side?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

Is such thing possible ?

```
     ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this.Page, this.GetType(), "Confirm", "x()", true);
    if (hid.Value != null)
    {
    }
    else
    {
    }

    function x() {
    var message = confirm("Are you sure you want to continue ?");
    if (message == true) {
        document.getElementById("hid").value = "1";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("hid").value = "0";
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want the return value from `confirm` to reach the server? If yes, you need ajax. Otherwise, you have code that already works on the client side.

Comment: No what i want is to call a javascript function and wait for the response, but when you call a javascript function that way it just continue and execute the javascript code after server side finished execution. @jade obviously i tried cause if so i wouldn't was my time and your time. Thanks.